# Git stash and git pull in vagrant

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

Having problem in using git pull and git stash it give me following error.

**fatal: cannot unlink '.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id': Permission denied**

Inside vagrant and if I use git pull then it will say that there some changes that need to be
pushed and thing is that I don't want these changes anymore.

So, if anyone can help in this.
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you add `.vagrant` to the ignored directories in your `.gitignore`. They should not be part of the stash

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to mess with the vagrant folder? You shouldn't touch that... it should be added to your .gitignore file.

To force a pull and lose your local changes you can reset.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```